Steenrod algebra as spectrum cohomology
I am learning basics about the Steenrod algebra (which I for this post define as the algebra of stable cohomology operations of ordinary mod $p$ cohomology, i.e. sequences of cohomology operations respecting suspensions) from John Rognes' lecture notes. Here, and in many other places, it is claimed the the Steenrod algebra is the same as $H \mathbb{F}_p^*H \mathbb{F}_p$, the $H \mathbb{F}_p$-cohomology of $H \mathbb{F}_p$. Although I am not particularly familiar with stable homotopy theory, I would like to understand why the above claim is true.
I saw this post and John Palmieri's answer, but I do not fully understand it. Let me instead tell you what I think:
First of all we have
$$H \mathbb{F}_p^*(-) = \pi_{-*}(\operatorname{map}(-,H \mathbb{F}_p)) = [\mathbb{S}^{-*},\operatorname{map}(-,H \mathbb{F}_p)] \cong [\mathbb{S}^{-*} \wedge - ,H \mathbb{F}_p)] \cong [-, \Sigma^* H \mathbb{F}_p]$$
via the hom-tensor adjunction and hence $H \mathbb{F}_p^*H \mathbb{F}_p \cong [H \mathbb{F}_p, \Sigma^* H \mathbb{F}_p]$. So this is the spectrum-level cohomology rewritten as homotopy classes of morphisms. This seems to be a nice way of saying what stable cohomology operations of degree $*$ are.
Now regarding the other side:
$$H^n(-,\mathbb{F}_p) \cong [(-)_+,K(\mathbb{F}_p,n)] \cong [\Sigma^{\infty}_+(-), \Sigma^n H \mathbb{F}_p]$$
and thus
$$\operatorname{Nat}(H^n(-,\mathbb{F}_p),H^m(-,\mathbb{F}_p)) \cong \operatorname{Nat}([\Sigma^{\infty}_+(-), \Sigma^n H \mathbb{F}_p],[\Sigma^{\infty}_+(-), \Sigma^m H \mathbb{F}_p]).$$
These are, of course, still unstable cohomology operations. Now I would like to say something along the lines of "If we pass to sequences of operations and restrict to the stable ones, then the stabilization on the right hand side vanishes." Then the right hand side would just be
$$\operatorname{Nat}([-, \Sigma^n H \mathbb{F}_p],[-, \Sigma^m H \mathbb{F}_p]) \cong [\Sigma^n H \mathbb{F}_p,\Sigma^m H \mathbb{F}_p] \cong [H \mathbb{F}_p,\Sigma^{m-n} H \mathbb{F}_p]$$
by using the Yoneda lemma. This is what we found above. What I seem to be missing is how to translate the stable operations directly into homotopy classes of morphisms of spectra. They do look very similar in the sense that both are defined by respecting suspensions, but I cannot seem to formalize this.

If you work directly with spectra (so that all the operations between them are by definition stable), then $H^n(-;\mathbb{F}_p) \cong [-, \Sigma^n H\mathbb{F}_p]$.  If we want to stick with spaces and possibly unstable operations, then $H^n(-;\mathbb{F}_p) \cong [-, K(\mathbb{F}_p, n)]$, so that operations are classified by maps between Eilenberg-MacLane spaces.

@JHF Just to be sure: When you say $H^n(-,\mathbb{F}_p)$ on the level of spectra, you just mean $H \mathbb{F}_p^n(-)$? If so, then I certainly agree with you as I also show in my post, but this does not seem to help me translate from the more concrete notion of stable operations which I am using. I might be missing something though.
